# HTTP response header tell client to use different port

Tags: http, http-headers

Is it possible to tell the client to use a different port to request source if not defined?

**Example**

I serve the client a web page on port 8080. The content of this website contains some links to other sources (e.g. img or style with src). The URI to this source is `http://localhost/requested_file`. By default the client will request this source on `http://localhost:80/requested_file` and I want the client to instead request `http://localhost:8080/requested_file`.

**Note**: I can manipulate the web server (and client) but NOT the source (e.g. served HTML, CSS and JS)

If not possible with HTTP response headers, maybe there is some other way (e.g. "injection" of JS in the response)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a linux server you could create a routing rule with iptables from one port to another such as:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
COMMIT
```

Comment: It is the Python3 HTTP server. For this question we could assume, that the server already uses port 80 for another service...